# prepared all combination of arraylist in java with arithmetic operator without duplicate combination

Tags: java, arraylist

Input: [first col, 
second col,
third col]

Output: first col, second col, third col, first col+second col, first col+third col, second col+third col
and so on for three col as well.

Note: i do not want same combination like: first col+second col and second col+first both are same. 
for three column like: a+b+c and b+c+a both are same. i dont want that duplicate column. please help me.

I tried with below code, but it is giving me a duplicate combination as well.

// Prepared combination..

```
 public static void perm2(ArrayList<String> a) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> sub = new ArrayList<String>();
        perm2(sub, a);
    }

    static String inputFileLocation = "";

    public static void perm2(ArrayList<String> sub, ArrayList<String> a)
            throws IOException {
        int L = a.size();
        int g = 0;
        String result = "";

        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        if (L != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                ArrayList<String> ab = new ArrayList<String>(sub);
                ab.add(a.get(i));
                ArrayList<String> bc = new ArrayList<String>(a);
                bc.remove(i);
                perm2(ab, bc);
                /* ArrayList to Array Conversion */
                String array[] = new String[ab.size()];
                for (int j = 0; j < ab.size(); j++) {
                    array[j] = ab.get(j);
                    System.out.println("Array: "+ array[j]);
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                    if (k == 0) {
                        result = array[k];
                    } else {
                        result = "+" + array[k];
                    }
                    System.out.print(result);
                    for (g = array.length; g > 0; g--) {
                        if (array.length == g) {
                            inputFileLocation = "C:\\project\\"
                                    + g + "ColumnData.txt";
                            writeToFile(result, inputFileLocation);
                        }
                    }
                }
                writeToFile(newLine, inputFileLocation);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code of what you have already tried and any exceptions/errors you encountered. Do not expect us to post a fully baked solution on demand as SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Do you need code? If so you are in wrong place.

Comment: Edit your question and put all the details including the code & error stack in it.

Comment: Thanks, but i not expecting whole code. i posted the code. please give me suggestion on that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through the full code yet but you can't do something like this:

```
bc.remove(i);
```

This statement will only hold good until the value of `i` remains less than the size of the list. Once, `i` becomes more than the size of the list, this will be a problem.

You should be doing something like this:

```
bc.remove(0);
```